# How to make C++ return lists of values or other sophisticated types to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to learn how to exchange data between C++ and QML. Consider the code below, which is a slightly modified version of [one of the Qt examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-referenceexamples-methods-example.html).

```
    // example.qml
    import QtQuick 2.0
    import People 1.0

    BirthdayParty {
        host: Person {
            name: "Bob Jones"
            shoeSize: 12
        }
        guests: [
            Person { name: "Leo Hodges" },
            Person { name: "Jack Smith" },
            Person { name: "Anne Brown" }
        ]

        Component.onCompleted:
           { console.log(invite("William Green").name)}
}
```

the interface files `Person.h` is

```
//Person.h
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <QObject>

class Person : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName)
    Q_PROPERTY(int shoeSize READ shoeSize WRITE setShoeSize)
public:
    Person(QObject *parent = 0);

    QString name() const;
    void setName(const QString &);

    int shoeSize() const;
    void setShoeSize(int);
private:
    QString m_name;
    int m_shoeSize;
};

#endif // PERSON_H
```

The interface file `birthday.h` is

```
#ifndef BIRTHDAYPARTY_H
#define BIRTHDAYPARTY_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlListProperty>

#include "person.h"

class BirthdayParty : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Person *host READ host WRITE setHost)
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<Person> guests READ guests)
public:
    BirthdayParty(QObject *parent = 0);

    Person *host() const;
    void setHost(Person *);

    QQmlListProperty<Person> guests();
    int guestCount() const;
    Person *guest(int) const;

    // Called from the QML side
    Q_INVOKABLE Person* invite(const QString &name);


private:
    Person *m_host;
    QList<Person *> m_guests;
};

#endif // BIRTHDAYPARTY_H
```

Both the `Person` and `BirthdayParty` C++ classes have been exposed to QML
by being registered with the QML type system via

```
qmlRegisterType<BirthdayParty>("People", 1,0, "BirthdayParty");
qmlRegisterType<Person>("People", 1,0, "Person");
```

in `main.cpp` (not pasted here for the sake of brevity).

Currently, when `BirthdayParty` component is completed, the code "invites"  another person "William Green" to the party. The invite method returns a pointer to this person, whose name can be accessed from the Javascript side and his name be printed via `console.log`

However, what if I wanted to return a ***list*** of people ( say the names of all the current guests to the party) back to QML? It seems to me according to [this](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html) page 
I would have to use `QVariantList` in some way. Is this correct? That page, unfortunately, just mentions how to call Javascript functions from C++ and not vice-versa so I am not sure how to proceed.

In, short my question is how does one ***return*** sophisticated data-types from C++ back to QML/Javascript.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you so much!

Comment: Plus one  for the shoe size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you want to expose a list of QObject, and in your code is already done through [QQmlListProperty](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmllistproperty.html):

```
Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<Person> guests READ guests)
```

then to obtain the elements you must do it in the style of js using length:

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    invite("William Green")
    for(var i=0; i < guests.length; i++){
        var guest = guests[i]
        console.log(guest.name)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
qml: Leo Hodges
qml: Jack Smith
qml: Anne Brown
qml: William Green
```

Comment: To expose a list of QObject, a `Q_PROPERTY` of type `QList<QObject*>` is enough. `QQmlListProperty` should be used when you need to populate the list declaratively from QML.